# Getting "TypeError: previewBuilder.corePresets is not iterable" when adding Storybook to new Next project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, storybook

I'm new to Storybook, but I've done some searching on this and come up empty.

I create a new NextJS project, added ESLint, Jest, and Tailwind, everything is fine.

I'm trying to add Storybook using these directions here: https://storybook.js.org/blog/get-started-with-storybook-and-next-js/

When I type yarn storybook, I'm getting this error"

```
info @storybook/react v6.4.18
info 
ERR! TypeError: previewBuilder.corePresets is not iterable
ERR!     at buildDevStandalone (/Users/james/Projects/TekPartners/InterviewQuestionBank/tekp_question_bank_fe/node_modules/@storybook/core-server/dist/cjs/build-dev.js:105:112)
ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
ERR!     at async buildDev (/Users/james/Projects/bank_fe/node_modules/@storybook/core-server/dist/cjs/build-dev.js:161:5)
ERR!  TypeError: previewBuilder.corePresets is not iterable
ERR!     at buildDevStandalone (/Users/james/Projects/bank_fe/node_modules/@storybook/core-server/dist/cjs/build-dev.js:105:112)
ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
ERR!     at async buildDev (/Users/james/Projects/bank_fe/node_modules/@storybook/core-server/dist/cjs/build-dev.js:161:5)
```

Like I said, I've been looking all over for a solution, but nothing. Just for fun, I created a couple of NextJS projects and tried installing SB right away (without setting up ESLint, Jest, or Tailwind) and I still get errors. I tried with and with out the WebPack option from the blog post, and all three give me different errors (I can provide the others if it helps).

ANY help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Storybook has now a command of migrating to v7. I had the same issue as you and got fixed after I did the upgrate as described here: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/migration-guide

Also if you're using yarn version lower that 2 the dlx command can be replaced with npx

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error during migration from webpack to vite.

You have to have

```js
// .storybook/main.js
  core: {
    builder: "@storybook/builder-vite",
  },
```

Also try to remove cache: `rm -rf node_modules/.cache`.

If you're using `vite` as your builder make sure that all webpack builder/managers was removed.

Comment: Is it possible to use webpack for the application and vite for storybook ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while migrating from webpack to vite, but the other answer didn't work for me. What did work was the following:

1. Backing up my `.storybook` directory
2. Uninstalling all storybook packages listed in my package.json e.g. `npm un @storybook/react @storybook/addon-actions`
3. Re-running the storybook setup script `npx @storybook/latest init`
4. Restoring any relevant settings from your backed up `.storybook` directory to the newly generated one

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue with vite storybook version 6.x.x, also i was facing issue with @alias then I have permormed below steps.

1. remove the .storybook folder
2. remove the all storybook related package from package.json
3. now setting up vite+storybook as my project setup in vite buileder
4. run `npx storybook@latest init`
   (below step optional if your project is normal i.e. not for an enterprize)
5. manually vite configuration(optional for normal project ) `yarn add --dev @storybook/builder-vite`
6. update `.storybook/main.ts` file for same configuration your `vite.config.ts`

```js
import { mergeConfig } from 'vite';
export default {
    stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
    addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials', '@storybook/addon-interactions'],
    framework: '@storybook/react',
    core: {
        builder: '@storybook/builder-vite',
    },
    async viteFinal(config) {
        // Merge custom configuration into the default config
        return mergeConfig(config, {
            // Add dependencies to pre-optimization
            optimizeDeps: {
                include: ['storybook-dark-mode'],
            },
        });
    },
    staticDirs: ['../public'],
};
```

done ;)
Note: current storybook version upgraded to 7.0.x